# PCB hanging upside down in its enclosure

Tags: pcb, enclosure, vibration, mounting-holes

Would this be a problem in a moderately high vibrations / shocks environment (passenger car interior) ?

The screws are 1.8 mm thread diameter, 5 mm long, the PCB being some 90 x 60 mm with nothing too heavy hanging from it and. The screws are on its four corners.

EDIT

the PCB is rather sparsely populated, about half of it not being covered by components. There are some 5 signal THT resistors, about 10 THT caps, a MCU, a radio transmitter, a PCB trace antenna, 2 SMT coils and 2 SMT caps, one connector block for the 12V power in, one grommet that secures the power cable to a side wall of the enclosure, one L78 SMD voltage regulator, and three THT protection components that are bulkier:

- An 1.8 g TVS diode: [5KP15A](https://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/5kp65)
- An 1.2 g reverse polarity protection diode: [LN5404](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28007.pdf)
- A 2.25 g power resistor: [AC05000002200JAC00](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28730/acac-at.pdf)

Comment: Hard to give a definite answer without more details on the PCB stackup, the vibration environment and what it's attached to, but - the fact that it's upside down probably won't make much difference.

Comment: It also matters what's on the board. A bunch of 0402 resistors won't stress it much, but a big heavy transformer would. a PTH resistor isn't likely to be damaged by moderate vibrations, but an SMT capacitor could be.

Comment: If you apply a force equal to the weight on the center of the board. does it flex easily?  That's 1 g

Comment: @pericynthion Edited

Comment: @ThePhoton IS that so about the SMT caps ? More details please. Also, edited the question.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist not sure how I could test that at home. Both applying such force and measuring the flex.

Comment: Is destructive testing an option?

Comment: @AndrewMorton could be. What did you have in mind ?

Comment: @kellogs It was only question as to what range of testing would be possible - you might be intending to manufacture a million of them or it might be a one-off project. What is the scale of your budget? What is the acceptable failure rate? Look at a typical music system in a car from the 1970s, 1980s, etc. Did they have problems with car vibrations?